# Classe abstrata para acessar elementos de uma coleção de objetos

Tags: c#, array, objetos, desserialização, coleção

Estou realizando meu primeiro projeto em C#, estou serializando os dados de um arquivo JSON com múltiplos objetos que contém informações básicas de um arquivo (NomeDoArquivo, DataCriação, Tamanho).

Arquivo `jsonArquivos.json`:

```
[  {
   "NomeDoArquivo" : "PrimeiroArquivo",
   "DataCriacao" : "10/10/2020",
   "Tamanho" : 200
}, {
   "NomeDoArquivo" : "TerceiroArquivo",
   "DataCriacao" : "09/09/2020",
   "Tamanho" : 250
}, {
   "NomeDoArquivo" : "SegundoArquivo",
   "DataCriacao" : "08/08/2020",
   "Tamanho" : 150
}  ]
```

Classe `Arquivo.cs`:

```
public class Arquivo {
  public String NomeDoArquivo { get; set; }
  public String DataCriacao{ get; set; }
  public int Tamanho{ get; set; }
}
```

Meu intuito é usar uma sequência de 10.000 objetos em uma coleção para aplicar um algoritmo de ordenação com a propriedade selecionada. Para tal, eu gostaria de criar um método que receba a propriedade selecionada e percorra todos os elementos para copiar em um array e reordenar os mesmos.
Algo como:

```
public void copiaArray(string propriedade, object obj){
   var[] vetorCopia = new var[arquivos.Count]; 
   // Não sei se posso fazer isso de ainda, talvez eu tenha que realizar uma versão para string[] e uma para int[].
   for(i=0; i<arquivos.Count; i++){
      vetorCopia[i] = arquivos[i].propriedade; 
   // Sei que posso acessar um objeto da collection por índice, mas não sei como acessar a propriedade a seguir do índice sem ter que especificar diretamente no código e ter que criar um método pra cada propriedade.
   }
}
```

Minhas dúvidas são:

Posso acessar a propriedade por índice também (`arquivos[i].[proprieade]`) ou sou obrigado a usar um `foreach` e de alguma forma comparar a propriedade passada?

Estou no melhor caminho para obter uma cópia array de uma específica propriedade da coleção?

Nota: Vim do Java, estou estudando ainda os termos C#, sintam-se a vontade para me corrigirem, estou muito raso ainda.
Nota2: Agradeço a atenção até então, e percebi que preciso esclarecer algumas coisas.
A ordenação que me referi anteriormente será variável de acordo com o algoritmo especificado posteriormente (bubbleSort, SelectionSort, QuickSort...)
O tipo de dado que estou obtendo após desserializar o json para coleção de objetos em meu TypeOf é System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ao qual pretendo percorrer por index, porém o mesmo possue sua própria lista de propriedades.

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List][index].NomeDoArquivo;
[System.Collections.Generic.List][index].DataCriacao;
[System.Collections.Generic.List][index].Propriedade;
```

Minha inteção era passar essa coleção por parâmetro para percorrer por index cada objeto, e também generalizar o acesso a proprieade (talvez por index tambem) para acessar de forma direta de acordo com uma definição por parâmetro.

```
static String[] transformaParaVetor(System.Collections.Generic.List, int Propriedade){
   for(i=0; i < [System.Collections.Generic.List].Count; i++){  
      str[i] = [System.Collections.Generic.List][index].[indexPropriedade]
   }
   return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se vocês está procurando ordenar uma lista eu recomendo usar Enublerable.OrderBy

Exemplo (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1):

```cs
minhaLista.OrderBy(x => x.Tamanho); //ou
minhaLista.OrderBy(x => x.DataCriacao); // ou
```

Porém se vc quer acessar as propriedades dinamicamente, existe dois caminhos para implementar sua ideia

### 1. Você pode usar indexadores em classes.

Seria algo como

```cs
public int this[int index]
{
    // get and set accessors
}
```

Segue o link da Microsoft de como implementar
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers

### 2. Reflexão

Algo parecido com:

```cs
public void metodo(string propriedade, object obj)
{
    object valorDaPropriedade = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propriedade).GetValue(obj);
    // ...
}
```

Segue o link da Microsoft
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Comment: Obrigado, desconhecia a reflexão, e ela vai me ser muito útil mesmo para finalizar o método desejado.